# How to write this formula in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, formula

I have this formula that I am struggling to write its Python equivalent:

[image: Beam Width Formula]

Where I(x,y) is an image in the form of a numpy array, with the intensity value accessible using a row-column index. xbar is the centroid x coordinate, which is known.

My attempt at code is below:

```
# centroid is a tuple of (x,y) of the coordinate position. image is a 2d array of the image.
import scipy.integrate as integrate

height, width = image.shape[0:2]

intensity_func = lambda x,y: image[y,x]
denom = int.dblquad(intensity_func, 0, height, lambda x: 0, lambda x: width)
x_f = lambda x,y: (x-centroid[0])**2 * intensity_func(x,y)
x_num = int.nquad(x_f, [[0, width],[0, height]])
sig_x = np.sqrt(x_num[0]/denom[0])

print 4*sig_x
```

Comment: and what's the problem exactly?

Comment: I don't know how to do it! I know my code isn't quite there and I don't know how to write the formula in python properly.

Comment: First, I wouldn't recommend to import some package as `int` since this is a reserved python keyword. Second, it seems that the square root is missing in the end. For the rest, it seems complex enough to be okay :) When it runs what's the problem you're encountering?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm getting this error: ng: The maximum number of subdivisions (50) has been achieved.
  If increasing the limit yields no improvement it is advised to analyze
  the integrand in order to determine the difficulties.  If the position of a
  local difficulty can be determined (singularity, discontinuity) one will
  probably gain from splitting up the interval and calling the integrator
  on the subranges.  Perhaps a special-purpose integrator should be used.
  warnings.warn(msg, IntegrationWarning)

Comment: Ooops. Beyond me. What I understand is that your integration is too general and too wide. The warning suggests that you use specialized integration formulae on several intervals. But this is only a warning, you should still get a result.